# Transfer of Websocket communication from server to client in Streaming

Tags: html, websocket

I'm new websocket streaming application.
I'm trying to evaluate kaazing and solace streaming vendor products.
I'm trying to put a layer or interface application infornt of kaazing publisher before it creates the socket connection.
The client would make request to the interface for the socket connection , the interface plays the role to authenticate and authorize and do some business changes before the creation of socket.
The interface establish the secured socket connection with kazzing or streaming application and transfer the connection object to the client in response.
The client use the established connection from the reponse and retains the connection for streaming the data to client from the streaming server.

The objective is to hide the topic info and connection established from the client side for secured process.
So the infterace creates the secured connection and transfers the connection to authorized client which continue the streaming from the streaming server until the session expires.
Please let me designing such an application is possible.

The client receives data but it doesn't establish connection of its own, its created from server side and transfered to client side after all necessary validation.

Guide me to proceed further with the design and I'm inneed of expert's valuable suggestion.
Thanks in advance and appriciated for directing me to the right path in designing the streaming appliation.

My aim is not to introduce a new layer between the gateway and client. Altimate aim is to customize the gateway for my product, For example the user(client) connects to gateway and tries to access the topic say stock(eligible to subscribe) then he will be able to get the data streaming. If he needs share he would register is some place and after approval only he will be eligible to view, So authorization would play a role and maintaince a session and loads the customized data and allows to stream.
Typically am trying to have a dashboard of data streaming. So only authorized streaming is allowed for user. Also he will be able to see all the topic name. whether its possible to use proxy name , example 1, or 2 might be the value he would use from client side, when it reaches the gateway it verify the authorization and replace the value with real topic name and establish the data.
Please let me know whether I've my question clear. Your valuable suggestions and guidance will be more helpful to continue with my research.

Thanks 
Krish

Comment: To add to simonc's comment: based on your description it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Can you clarify? Do you want to introduce an extra layer between your WebSocket gateway and your JavaScript client? If so, can you describe the justification for it? It would be similar to introducing a layer between your HTTP server and your HTTP client... Also, you may want to review a couple of WebSocket security related articles: http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/28/html5-websocket-security-is-strong/, http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/29/kaazing-websocket-gateway-security-is-strong/.

Comment: Thank you for simonc and Peter. I've explained my scenerio and please let me have the update

Answer (score 0):

in case you wonder how the world has changed over the last five year to address this kind of need, now you could give a try to streamdata.io, a proxy which uses [SSE protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (unidirectional) and is available in minutes. It would perfectly fit what's needed in the example given, because Im not sure WebSocket is the ideal answer here. Tho it should work, it's basically like buying a harvester to go get your kids at school.

As a disclaimer, I need to say that I work for Streamdata, and we see this kind of thing every day.

WebSocket is great if you need bidirectional streams of data, like in chats or games. Most of the time, when the clients mainly expect updated data from the server, instead of polling AF or deploying WebSocket, SSE is the best alternative as it's easier to deploy (http, etc.). The rest of the settings (for security) can be done through the proxy interface.

Boom: it's available before you even realize it, it's secure, easy to maintain and more efficient than before. You have more time available to answer questions from the community over here; your team is happy; your boss loves you more than before and might even give you a raise. Life can be so simple sometimes!